# SSRS Switch statement in Expression is not working (color code a polygon in a chart)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that breaks down financials by state. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

That is the tablix version of the data. I also have a chart as a map where I want to display the data visually.

The actual data is broken up like this:

```
NM City   100
NJ City1  100
NJ City2  100
NJ City3  100
NY City   100
NY City2  100
```

In SSRS, each state is a polygon. 
[image]
I want to set the fill color of that polygon to be a color based on the Total Value of that state.

The best way to do this would be to just set the color value equal to my formula against the total value. Then I would use that same line of code for every polygon and it would color code accordingly.

However, I do not think the polygons know which state they belong to. For example, is there any way to get the New York Polygon to only look at the NY state value?

In case there isn't, I'm trying to so a switch statement where for every polygon I'll have it only get the value where the state name equals whatever I manually input.

```
=SWITCH 
(Max(Fields!State.Value, "CustomersByState") = "NE" , "10000"
 Max(Fields!State.Value, "CustomersByState") = "NY" , "20000"
 1=1,"Coral")
```

When I have that line be as the expression for the label name of that polygon (for testing, if I can make this work I can make anything work) it gives me an error and says comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a comma after "10000" and "20000"

Comment: That fixed the error but now the code always seems to default to the default Coral option. EDIT: It is because I am using MAX in front of the field. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Is the State name in your primary reporting resultset?  If so, try taking out the "CustomersByState" scope.  For troubleshooting, put a text box somewhere on the report and display the value.  EDIT: I don't know your report well enough to answer that question.

Comment: Yeah so thats my problem. I have two datasets which makes SSRS force me to use an aggregrate like First or Sum which makes me unable to use my equation. Do you know any way around this?

Comment: I repeat - Is `State` in your primary reporting resultset?

Comment: Another thought: have a separate result set that only has the state and the total numbers (your initial question did not include column headers).  Then paint the map based on that result set.  I do that frequently in my reports.